# Using function IN and OR in SAS data set

Tags: sas

I have a data set WHERE condtion where I have rejection codes 75 or 76, how can I tell sas that in these 3 columns I want data where rejection code 1 , 2 and 3 have either code 75, code 76, or both?

```
**0 Grab pskw;
data pskw_data;
set PSKW.PSKWMaster;
where week in ('12-16-2016','12-23-2016','12-30-2016','01-06-2016') and CopayType ="FBD" and FNRX=1 and pme_id in (46,42,55,38) and COBPrimaryRejectCode1 in ( '75','76')  or COBPrimaryRejectCode2  in ('75','76') or COBPrimaryRejectCode3  or ('75','76');
run;
```

Comment: Try: `where week in ('12-16-2016','12-23-2016','12-30-2016','01-06-2016') and CopayType ="FBD" and FNRX=1 and pme_id in (46,42,55,38) and (COBPrimaryRejectCode1 in ( '75','76')  or COBPrimaryRejectCode2  in ('75','76') or COBPrimaryRejectCode3 in ('75','76'));`

Comment: I think this worked!

Comment: Just for clarity:  `OR` and `IN` are not functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some `( )`;

```
data pskw_data;
set PSKW.PSKWMaster;
where week in ('12-16-2016','12-23-2016','12-30-2016','01-06-2016') 
               and CopayType ="FBD" and FNRX=1 and pme_id in (46,42,55,38) 
               and 
               (
                 COBPrimaryRejectCode1 in ( '75','76')  
                 or COBPrimaryRejectCode2  in ('75','76') 
                 or COBPrimaryRejectCode3  in ('75','76')
               );
run;
```

I added formatting so you can see the clause better.

You want all the things above the `()` to be true AND the stuff inside the `()` to be true.

The stuff inside the `()` contains the or clauses.  Having them ungrouped was causing your problems.